# Using VBA to format/process mail merge field data

Tags: vba, email, merge, ms-word, format

I'd like to write a VBA function which will covnert the currency data into text format. The currency data is from mail merge field.

Source data: 8900

Result: Eight Thousands Nine Hundred dollars

**Code in mind (Didn't work):**

{ IF `{` {MERGEFIELD Price `}` <> "" getPriceInWords(`{` DOCVARIABLE PRICE `}`) "" )

Answer (score 0):

The code is in following page, which is provided by Microsoft.

http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/213360/en-us